# How to iteratively nest a nested function

Tags: python, numpy, loops, for-loop, concatenation

I have an array `arr_multi_dim` which is multi-dimensional. Every time when I increase a parameter n, there will be more entries created in the array results and the array will get larger.

With each increase in `n`, I need to perform the function `np.concatenate()` on the array `arr_multi_dim`, in such a way that there will be more `np.concatenate()` function nested every time `n` increases.

For eg.,

when n=2:

```
arr_multi_dim = np.concatenate(np.concatenate(arr_multi_dim, axis=1), axis=1)
```

when n=3:

```
arr_multi_dim = np.concatenate(np.concatenate(
                np.concatenate(np.concatenate(arr_multi_dim, axis=1), axis=1), axis=1), axis=1)
```

when n=4:

```
arr_multi_dim = np.concatenate(np.concatenate(
                np.concatenate(np.concatenate(
                np.concatenate(np.concatenate(arr_multi_dim, axis=1), axis=1), axis=1), axis=1), axis=1), axis=1)
```

etc.

where at each increment of `n`, a pair of `np.concatenate()` (ie. two) gets added into the function.

How do I write a function, loops (or something similar), so that when I specify any values for `n`, the appropriate `np.concatenate()` function will be used?

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

This is the full code that I have written which uses the above `np.concatenate()` function.

```
from itertools import product
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
import numpy as np

lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
arr = np.array(lst)
n = 2

def test1(arr, n):
    flat = np.ravel(arr).tolist()
    gen = (list(a) for a in product(flat, repeat=n))

    results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(reduce)(mul, x) for (x) in gen)

    nrows = arr.shape[0]
    ncols = arr.shape[1]

    arr_multi_dim = np.array(results).reshape((nrows, ncols)*n)
    arr_final = np.concatenate(np.concatenate(arr_multi_dim, axis=1), axis=1)  # need to generalise this

    return arr_final
```

The above code only works for n=2. I am trying to generalize the `np.concatenate` part of the code so that it would work for any `n` as mentioned above.

Comment: can you provide an example of input/output you want? like your result and n and the output you want, I think there must be a much simpler way than calling concatenate multiple times

Comment: can you show a dummy of how `results` looks like?

Comment: Hi @S.Mohsensh, I have updated my question above as requested. This code is doing a self-Kronecker product (ie, Kronecker product of it's own matrix). I am experimenting if I could write my own code for this and parallelize this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @dzang, I have updated my question above as requested. This code is doing a self-Kronecker product (ie, Kronecker product of it's own matrix with `n` representing how many times the Kronecker product is performed). I am experimenting if I could write my own code for this and parallelize this. Many thanks.

Comment: @Leockl thanks, can you also add the imports to the needed function to reproduce your example?

Comment: Hi @dzang, apologies. Added thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly its pretty simple:

```
arr_multi_dim = results
for i in range(n):
  if i < 2:
    arr_multi_dim = np.concatenate(arr_multi_dim , axis=1)
  else:
    arr_multi_dim = np.concatenate(np.concatenate(arr_multi_dim , axis=1), axis=1)
```

becase the first two iteration only add a single layer while the rest add two layers

Comment: Thank heaps @Nullman for pointing to the right direction. Working out now what values of the counters in the for loop should take.

Comment: @Leockl I updated my answer with what i think are the correct counters in your situation

Comment: Many thanks @Nullman. I feel so dumb right now as I wasn't able to see this.